# From where can i find small introduction to all AI algorithms for non techy person

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm, heuristics

I know that AI is vast field and there are many algorithms which exist there.
I have tried learning from wikipedia but thats too much math stuff which i didn't understand.

Is there any place from where i can find the 7-8 lines of brief introduction on each algorithm and which can tell me that  for which type of problems we can use which algorithm.

E,g something like IF we need to find some shortest route t0o some destination then we can use shortest path algorithm. Currently there are so much variery of fields like Bayesian methods , meakov chain models , optimization algorithms which i am not able to get what type of proeblems can be solved by them.

I jsut want to know what athey are capable of doi ng rather than hard core math stuff which always goes on the top of my head

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is for specific programming and programmer tools related question, not general discussion questions. It's also not a replacement for a search engine or doing your own research. Voting to close as "not constructive". Please feel free to ask actual coding related questions once you get started writing some. If you can't understand the math, perhaps that's what you should start learning first.

Answer (score 1):

aaai.org has some good introductory articles. 
http://aitopics.net/AIOverview

machine learning 101: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598726/overwhelmed-by-machine-learning-is-there-an-ml101-book/598772#598772